# Install SSL Certificate in Iceweasel

Tags: firefox, ssl, kali-linux, iceweasel

I'm using Kali on Windows. I downloaded the [Burp Suite](http://www.portswigger.net/burp/download.html) and I'm trying to install its SSL certificate onto the Iceweasel browser.

> Burp Suite, the leading toolkit for web application security testing

But when I go to import the certificate file, it doesn't show up. I saved the file onto the desktop.

Here's a screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Change the dropdown above "open" that says "Certificate Files" to "All files".

Comment: Thank youuuuuuuuu!!  (although how come it doesnt work with "Certificate Files"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the file on your desktop, but it has no extension, and you are filtering by extension ("Certificate Files" is selected in the filetype dropdown, and this probably filters to common certificate extensions). Either rename the file to have the correct extension (probably `.pem`), or change the dropdown to say "All files" or similar.