# Install root SSL certificate

Tags: kali-linux, openssl, certificates, iceweasel

I created root certificates, and server certificate, signed with root. How can I install my root certificate, to remove warning about untrusted connection? *update, dpkg-reconfigure* don't work. I'm using OpenSSL, Iceweasel browser, on Kali Linux v.1.1.0

**EDIT**

Steps:
Creating secret key of root CA:

```
dd if=/dev/random of=.rnd count=64 bs=32
openssl genrsa -rand .rnd -out org.key 2048
```

Creating certificate request:

```
openssl req  -new -key org.key -config org.cnf -out org.csr
```

with:

```
org.cnf
[ req ] 
default_bits = 2048 
distinguished_name = req_distinguished_name 
extensions = v3_req 
x509_extensions = usr_cert 
[ req_distinguished_name ] 
countryName = US 
countryName_default = US 
stateOrProvinceName  = City
stateOrProvinceName_default = City
localityName = City
localityName_default = City 
organizationName = Company
organizationName_default = Company
organizationalUnitName = CA 
organizationalUnitName_default = CA 
commonName = CAuthority 
commonName_default = CAuthority 
emailAddress = master@ex.com
emailAddress_default = master@ex.com
[ v3_req ] 
basicConstraints = CA:TRUE 
nsComment = "CA certificate of PTI" 
nsCertType = sslCA 
[ usr_cert ]
# These extensions are added when 'ca' signs a request.
basicConstraints=critical,CA:TRUE
```

Creating root CA:

```
openssl  x509 -req -signkey org.key -in org.csr -extfile org.cnf -out org.crt -days 1830
```

That's all for root, now I need to create server certificate, to install it on Apache. Creating secret key:

```
dd if=/dev/urandom of=.rnd count=64 bs=32;
openssl genrsa -rand .rnd -out httpd.key 2048;
```

Creating certificate request:

```
openssl req  -new -key httpd.key -config httpd.cnf -out httpd.csr
```

with:

```
httpd.cnf
[ req ] 
default_bits = 2048 
distinguished_name = req_distinguished_name 
extensions = v3_req 
x509_extensions = usr_cert 
[ req_distinguished_name ] 
countryName = country [US] 
countryName_default = US 
stateOrProvinceName  = province [City] 
stateOrProvinceName_default = City 
localityName = locality [City] 
localityName_default = City
organizationName = organization [Company] 
organizationName_default = Company
organizationalUnitName = OU_name 
organizationalUnitName_default = Webserver 
commonName = commonName 
commonName_default = "localhost" 
emailAddress = email 
emailAddress_default = webmaster@ex.com
[ v3_req ] 
basicConstraints = CA:false 
nsComment = "Apache Server Certificate" 
nsCertType = server
[ usr_cert ]
# These extensions are added when 'ca' signs a request.
basicConstraints=critical,CA:TRUE
```

After all, I sign *httpd.csr* with this command:

```
openssl ca -notext -in httpd.csr -cert org.crt -keyfile org.key -out httpd.crt -md sha1 -days 90 -verbose;
```

Then I install my *httpd.crt* and *httpd.key* to Apache, so, when I'm trying get *https localhost*, it says "Connection Untrusted". Adding *httpd.crt* to Authorities in Iceweasel, have no effect. Still "Untrusted Connection".

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/125731/install-ssl-certificate-in-iceweasel

Comment: @garethTheRed I can add root certificate only to Authorities, I can't add it to My certificates, it asked password, but i created certificate without paswword.

Comment: Hi @YuriyN., your question is not clear enough. You should try adding a better explanation of what you're trying to achieve and also include details about the commands you have tried so far. Please check the FAQ for how to ask good questions: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/18588/160115

Comment: @forcefsck I have my _root.crt, root.key, root.cnf_ files, they represented my root certificate. I have _server.pem,_ which signed by _root.crt,_ it already installed on apache2, now I have "This Connection is Untrusted", when I'm trying to get _https localhost_ in Iceweasel. So, the main question is, how to install the root certificate in Iceweasel, when I'm trying to import _org.crt_ in Authorities, Iceweasel alerts me "This is not a certificate authority certificate, so it can't be imported into the certificate authority list.". That's the problem. I don't know what to do.

Comment: @YuriyN., you should edit your question and add the relevant info there. Try to be more detailed, it would really help to include the commands you entered so far for creating your ca and server certs.

Also, you mentioned that you used `root.crt` for signing your webserver's certificate, but then you tried to import `org.crt`? Shouldn't you try to import the `root.crt`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set `CA:True` as a basic extension on the `root.crt`.

The browser will not allow you to add a non-CA certificate to the `Authorities` list which is why you are getting the error message.

You can check whether this extension is in the certificate with:

```
openssl x509 -noout -text -in root.crt
```

This will print a textual representation of your certificate which you can search for the following extract:

```
X509v3 Basic Constraints: critical
    CA:TRUE
```

If it's not there, you'll need to modify your `openssl` config file and add the following to the block pointed to by `x509_extensions`:

```
basicConstraints = critical, CA:TRUE
```

[man x509v3_config](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/apps/x509v3_config.html) will give you all the details, but here's an example from the `openssl.cnf` file on a Fedora 23 box:

```
####################################################################
[ ca ]
default_ca  = CA_default        # The default ca section

####################################################################
[ CA_default ]

dir     = /etc/pki/CA       # Where everything is kept
certs       = $dir/certs        # Where the issued certs are kept
crl_dir     = $dir/crl      # Where the issued crl are kept
database    = $dir/index.txt    # database index file.
#unique_subject = no            # Set to 'no' to allow creation of
                    # several ctificates with same subject.
new_certs_dir   = $dir/newcerts     # default place for new certs.

certificate = $dir/cacert.pem   # The CA certificate
serial      = $dir/serial       # The current serial number
crlnumber   = $dir/crlnumber    # the current crl number
                    # must be commented out to leave a V1 CRL
crl     = $dir/crl.pem      # The current CRL
private_key = $dir/private/cakey.pem# The private key
RANDFILE    = $dir/private/.rand    # private random number file

x509_extensions = usr_cert      # The extentions to add to the cert
```

You'll notice that `x509_extensions` points to a section further down in the file called `usr_cert` which has the following:

```
[ usr_cert ]

# These extensions are added when 'ca' signs a request.

basicConstraints=CA:TRUE
```

Note that the name `user_cert` is simply that - a name, therefore the fact that your certificate is a CA certificate has no bearing.  If you suffer from OCD, then you can change `usr_cert` to `CA_cert` in both.

The above should be added to the configuration file you are using. That is, if you are not adding the `-config` option to the `openssl` command then it will use the distro's default config file. This is usually in the OpenSSL's default directory which can be found with:

```
openssl version -d
```

Comment: if I don't have block pointed by `x509_extensions`, should I do something like this in _/etc/ssl/openssl.conf_:
`[ x509_extensions ]
basicConstraints = critical, CA:TRUE`
and add it somewhere in file?
Also, should I add this block to _org.cnf_?

Comment: Added an example. What is `org.cnf` and where does that come into things?

Comment: _org.cnf_ i used in this command `openssl req  -new -key org.key -config org.cnf -out org.csr`.

Comment: Then add the suggested changes to `org.cnf`; not the system wide `openssl.cnf` file.

Comment: Added steps of my solution.

Comment: You have added `CA:TRUE` to the web-server certificate too - the web-server isn't a CA as it's a web-server :-)  so you should remove that from that certificate.  Have you added the root certificate you've created to Iceweasel?  If you wish, you can list both certificates with `openssl x509 -noout -text -in <certificate filename>`.  Add the output of this command for both certificates to your question.  Finally, you've signed your certificate with the SHA1 hash.  This is now deprecated and you should use SHA256 as a minimum.